# The minimizers of energy and length of a curve

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, geodesic

Assume S is a regular surface with a Riemannian metric $g$.

The energy of a curve $c: [0,a] \to S$  is defined as :

$$ E(c) = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^a g_{c(t)}(\dot c(t),\dot c(t))\mathsf{dt} $$

This is quite similar to the definition of the length in terms of the defining functions i.e.:

$$L(c) = \int_0^a \sqrt{g_{c(t)} (\dot c(t), \dot c(t) )}\mathsf{dt}$$

The Lemma 2.3 in Chapter 9 of Riemannian Geometry by Do Carmo is:

[image]

About the formula
$$aE(\gamma)=(L(\gamma))^2\leq (L(c))^2\leq aE(c),$$
the author has proved the inequality: $$(L(c))^2\leq aE(c)$$
using the Schwarz inequality.

The question is: why $aE(\gamma)=(L(\gamma))^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any smooth curve $c : [0,a] \to M$, choosing $f \equiv 1$ and $g=|c'(t)|$ the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$
\Big( \int_0^a fg \,\, \text{d}t\Big)^2 \leq \int_0^a f^2 \, \text{d}t \int_0^a g^2 \, \text{d}t,
$$
become $L(c)^2 \leq aE(c)$. But Cauchy-Schwarz inequality become an equality if and only if $g$ is constant, which means that $L(c)^2 = aE(c)$ if and only if $|c'(t)| = \text{const}$.

Apply this inequality to the curve $\gamma$ in the lemma, we certainly have $L(\gamma)^2 \leq aE(\gamma) $. Since by hypotheses, $\gamma$ is a geodesic ( i.e. $D\gamma'/dt = 0$ ), a simple computation
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \langle \gamma',\gamma' \rangle = \Big\langle \frac{D\gamma'}{dt}, \gamma'\Big\rangle + \Big\langle  \gamma', \frac{D\gamma'}{dt}  \Big\rangle = 0,
$$
implies the speed $|\gamma'(t)|$ is constant. Therefore $L(\gamma)^2 = aE(\gamma)$.

Comment: Why $\Big\langle  \gamma', \frac{D\gamma'}{dt}  \Big\rangle = 0$? Is this a property of geodesic? We don't assume that the curve has a constant speed. If the curve $\gamma(t)$ has a constant speed, we reparameterize it as $\gamma(\phi(s))$. Is the new one satisfies $\Big\langle  \gamma', \frac{D\gamma'}{ds}  \Big\rangle = 0$?

Comment: @W.mu A geodesic exactly defined by its acceleration vector $D\gamma'/dt$ equal to zero.